# Why is VIM not listening to local .editorconfig?

Tags: macos, vim

I'm just trying to use editorconfig for the first time, and for some reason it doesn't appear to be reading local configuration files. This is on MacOS 11.2.1, with VIM 8.2.

I installed as a [VIM 8 plugin](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vim#install-as-vim8-plugin), and the installation seems to have worked, because

`:verbose set tabstop?`

`tabstop=8 Last set from ~/.vim/pack/local/start/editorconfig-vim/plugin/editorconfig.vim line 388`

However, that's not what I expect, because that's VIM's response while editing webpack.config.js in a directory that has a .editorconfig file, thusly:

```
root = true

[*]
indent_size = 8
indent_style = tab

[*.{json, js, html}]
indent_size = 2

[*.css]
indent_size = 4
```

I'm not sure if this is an editorconfig problem, or if I need to do something with VIM to make it read the local files (though it seems I shouldn't because [the docs say](https://editorconfig.org),

> When opening a file, EditorConfig plugins look for a file named
> .editorconfig in the directory of the opened file and in every parent
> directory. A search for .editorconfig files will stop if the root
> filepath is reached or an EditorConfig file with root=true is found.
>
> EditorConfig files are read top to bottom and the most recent rules
> found take precedence. Properties from matching EditorConfig sections
> are applied in the order they were read, so properties in closer files
> take precedence.

The docs also say,

> **indent_size**: a whole number defining the number of columns used for
> each indentation level and the width of soft tabs (when supported).
> When set to tab, the value of tab_width (if specified) will be used.
>
> **tab_width**: a whole number defining the number of columns used to
> represent a tab character. This defaults to the value of indent_size
> and doesn't usually need to be specified.

So, I'm expecting it to be set to "2". Anyone else experience this, or have a solution? Have I missed something obvious?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a trivial error. It was (correctly) matching on whitespace in the config, so, instead of

`[*.{json, js, html}]`

I needed

`[*.{json,js,html}]`

Comment: Thanks, I fell into this nasty trap.